# como insertar css a un formulario de django?

Tags: python, css, django, django-models, django-forms

¿como insertar css a un formulario de django?

VIEWS.PY

```
def contacto(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = ContactoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contacto = form.save(commit=False)
            contacto.save()
            return redirect('contacto')
    else:
        form = ContactoForm()
    return render(request,'Contacto.html',{'form': form})
```

FORMS.PY

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contacto

class ContactoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Contacto

        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Falta el codigo de Contacto.html, edita la pregunta y agrega ese codigo para entender mejor como tienes la estructura.

Comment: no me deja ingresar algo mas

Comment: @Jeison Da una explicación más de lo que deseas asi el sistema te permitira añadir más código